# Избежать одновременной обработки двух запросов Express, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

У меня есть приложение с розыгрышами. Пользователь просто должен нажать кнопку, отправится запрос на API на Express, пользователь внесется как учавствующий в базу MongoDB и ответим пользователю об успешном выполнении запроса.

Но если отправить в одно время два таких запроса, то пользователь может попасть в одну раздачу два или более раз.

Каким образом этого можно избежать? Хороший ли способ хранить массив с пользователями для которых уже обрабатывается такой запрос? А если разновидностей таких запросов множество?

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить ограничение для коллекции розыгрышей на уникальность поля имени пользователя:

```
db.lottery.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

После чего попытка вставить документ с не уникальным полем `name` вызовет ошибку, что будет означать, что этот пользователь уже участвует в розыгрыше.
Как бонус, можно быть уверенным, что в коллекции всегда уникальные пользователи, даже если они добавляются каким-то другим скриптом (написанным другим программистом).